# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{{1\cdot2}} + \frac{1}{{2\cdot3}} + \frac{1}{{3\cdot4}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{{n(n + 1)}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, telescopic-series

> Calculate

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{1\cdot2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot4} +  \cdots + \frac{1}{n(n + 1)}\right).
$$

If reduce to a common denominator we get

$$\lim _{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{X}{{n!(n + 1)}}\right).$$

How can I find $X$ and calculate limit?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Plug this into your sum and see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit you want to have calculated is the following
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}.$$
Note that $\tfrac{1}{k(k+1)}=\tfrac{1}{k}-\tfrac{1}{k+1}$, so this is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), meaning that consecutive terms cancel eachother out. It is then easy to see that for all $n$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
Now the limit is easy to evaluate; we find that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 3):

We can write sum as  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{r\cdot (r+1)}\right] = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right]$

Now Using Telescopin Sum(or Simply open Sigma)

We get Sum $\displaystyle  = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1-0 =1$

Answer (score 1):

This won't get you far. Try $\frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n + 1 - n}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1}$ instead.